# Same code base for WPF and Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'm willing to build a simple database application using `Silverlight`. Is it possible to use that code base as a WPF application? Final goal is to have exactly one code base to serve both as a Desktop application and as a Web application.

Comment: I would think so.  AFAIK, Silverlight uses a subset of the .NET framework, WPF the whole thing.  Assuming the Silverlight app doesn't use third party libraries, it should be considered a valid WPF app too.

Comment: @Jeff - there are actually some things Silverlight can do that WPF can't so it's not as simple as SL being a "subset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between the XAML that Silverlight and WPF support so you won't be able to do it this way.

What you will be able to do though is create a Full Trust Application in Silverlight that can be installed onto the desktop.

Comment: What sort of differences are we talking about here? Aren't they all the same really? Just supporting different versions of the framework?

Comment: @Jeff there are constructs that are subtly different between the two. For example the default binding in Silverlight is `OneWay`, but it's `TwoWay` in WPF (I think - don't do much WPF).

Answer (score 1):

Yes don't bother building the WPF application.  Build it all in Silverlight and allow the Silverlight app to be installed as an Out of browser app.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers on just do Silverlight in a Full Trust. WPF is not limited to HTTP and that is a good thing.  I have an application that is primarily used internally with WPF clients.  For external clients (on the other side of the firewall) I a will build Silverlight client.  What I did was build business objects that can hopefully be consumed by both WPF and Silverlight.  For performance and features I need WPF.  Silverlight has some stuff WPF does not - e.g. autocomplete but for the most part WPF is beefier.